# how to remove pdf studio from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, bash, pdf

Recently I installed PDF Studio 11, Trial(Evaluation) Version. As far as I remember, I downloaded it from their website, and the file "PDFStudio_v11_0_2_linux.sh" is at /home/.../Downloads. In addition, there are two folders "pdfstudio 11" and  ".pdfstudio 11" at  /home/. Now I want to remove this application, but am unable to do so. Terminal commands like "purge" etc are "unable to locate it". The application does not appear in Synaptic Package Manager either.

More importantly, their official website advises the user to go to /home/pdfstudio 11, right-click the shell script "uninstall" and then click the "Run in terminal" option. I did find and right-click the "uninstall" shell script, but the "Run in terminal" option didn't show up at all. Can anyone help me get over this annoying problem?

Comment: that dir seems weird. I'd expect it to be /home/$USER/pdfstudio 11/?

Comment: Oh, yes. There's my user name in place of the dots.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions assume you use Nautilus to go to the directory. That will have a context menu with "run in terminal".

But when you are doing it already from a terminal when you get to the directory type ...

```
./uninstall.sh
```

and it will start removing the software.

Comment: Thanks, but I am a novice, so could you be a little more detailed?

Comment: Thanks, but I am a novice, so could you be a little more detailed?   By "Nautilus" you mean "Dash", don't you? I used that to get to the "PDFStudio_v11_0_2_linux.sh" file at  /home/subrata (=my user name)/Downloads,  right-clicked the .sh file, but didn't get the "Run in terminal" option. And I can't make any headway at all with Terminal. You have probably provided the final command for the removal. Could you please give the earlier commands from the very beginning? I'd  appreciate that very much as I really want to get rid of the software that is of no use to me ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Set path of terminal to the folder contain the file "uninstall" then try the following command at terminal

```
sh uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go inside the folder for PDFStudio located in the `Home` folder. There is a file named `uninstall`. Open a terminal *in that folder* and run `./uninstall`. A window will pop up and guide you through the uninstallation.